# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection reset by peer in Flutter HttpClient

Tags: flutter, httpclient

Frequently getting the below error in flutter while trying to call API request in SIT/
UAT environment

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), address = cap.opyght.in, port = 40906
```

and the below is the sample API request,

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse("https://ex.in/mobi/api/v1/dashboard/mob"));
   request.headers.set('content-type', "application/json");
   request.headers.set('connection', 'keep-alive');
   request.write(encrtptedRequestData);
    HttpClientResponse _httpResponse = await request.close();
```

can any one suggest the best approach to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Handling the exception in the following way, retrying the call in case of any socket exception receives,

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClient();
    const maxRetries = 3;
    var retries = 0;
    while (true) {
      try {
        HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(_serverUrl));
        request.headers.set('content-type', "application/json");
       
        request.write(encrtptedRequestData);

        HttpClientResponse _httpResponse = await request.close();
        if (_httpResponse != null && _httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
          String _responseData = await _httpResponse.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        } 
        await request.close();
        // Handle successful response
        break; // Break out of loop if request succeeds
      } on SocketException catch (e) {
        // Handle SocketException
        retries++;
        if (retries > maxRetries) {
          // Retry limit reached, show error message to user
          break;
        } else {
          // Wait for a delay before retrying
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle other errors
        break;
      }
    }
    client.close();
```